# Storing Python dictionary entries in the order they are pushed

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, mapping

A Python dictionary is stored in no particular order (mappings have no order), e.g.

```
>>> myDict = {'first':'uno','second':'dos','third':'tres'}
myDict = {'first':'uno','second':'dos','third':'tres'}
>>> myDict
myDict
{'second': 'dos', 'third': 'tres', 'first': 'uno'}
```

While it is possible to retrieve a sorted list or tuple from a dictionary, I wonder if it is possible to make a dictionary store the items in the order they are passed to it, in the previous example this would mean having the internal ordering as `{'first':'uno','second':'dos','third':'tres'}` and no different.

I need this because I am using the dictionary to store the values as I read them from a configuration file; once read and processed (the values are altered), they have to be written to a new configuration file in the same order as they were read (this order is not alphabetical nor numerical).

Any thoughts?

Please notice that I am not looking for secondary ways to retrieve the order (like lists), but of ways to make a dictionary be ordered in itself (as it will be in upcoming versions of Python).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared

Comment: @ Ofri Raviv: exact same question. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're trying to maintain order, it's not really a dictionary in the first place.  You're doing too many things.  You might want both dictionary (for the mapping) and list (to retain the order).  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @S.Lott: You are right - no need to force a data structure into a different behavior than it was designed for. I will create my own or use the ones already described here. Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try python 2.7 and above, probably 3.1, there is OrderedDict

http://www.python.org/

http://python.org/download/releases/2.7/

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict([('first', 1), ('second', 2),
...                  ('third', 3)])
>>> d.items()
[('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3)]
```

[PEP 372: Adding an ordered dictionary to collections](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-372-adding-an-ordered-dictionary-to-collections)

Comment: Nice. But keep in mind that is a new feature of an upcoming Python release and is not available in older versions.

Comment: ... but I'm stuck with 2.5.1 :(

Comment: Or get the source code of the OrderedDict from this patch: http://bugs.python.org/issue5397

Comment: If you look at the PEP (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/) you'll find a list of implementations of ordered dictionaries for older pythons. If performance isn't an issue I'd suggest using their own sample implementation of odict (http://dev.pocoo.org/hg/sandbox/raw-file/tip/odict.py), which you'll be able to swap for the standard library one if you ever upgrade.

Comment: It's important as well, if its possible to push to an ordered Dict, this is in some applications essential. Otherweise you have to build-up the OrderedDict everytime you have a new element from a dict.

Comment: great, I was looking for this only. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use a list to hold the key order

Comment: quick and dirty. alas, not very compact (can get brittle).

Comment: This works, but I am looking for a more "natural" way, if there is one. It seems that the OrderedDict suggested by S.Mark is the alternative I was looking for. Unfortunately I am stuck with Python 2.5.1 :(

Comment: Not if you encapsulate the dict and list in a single object with dict interface. Which, by the way, is what many Ordered Dict implementations do (don't know about the implementation actually adopted in 2.7)

Answer (score 3):

Implementations of order-preserving dictionaries certainly do exist.

There is [this one in Django](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/datastructures.py), confusingly called `SortedDict`, that will work in Python >= 2.3 iirc.

Comment: Just noticed this is going to be deprecated in Django 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries in Python are implemented as hash tables, which is why the order appears random.  You could implement your own variation of a dict that sorts, but you'd lose out on the convenient syntax.  Instead, keep track of the order of the keys, too.

Initialization:

```
keys = []
myDict = {}
```

While reading:

```
myDict[key] = value
keys.append(key)
```

While writing:

```
for key in keys:
  print key, myDict[key]
```

Comment: My keys are not in alphabetical or numerical order :( They can be anything.

Comment: You wouldn't need to lose out on any syntax. Simply implement special methods such as __get__() and __set__() etc so enable use of syntax like dict['key'] and dict['key1'] = newvalue.

Answer (score 2):

Rather Than Explaining The Theoretical  Part I'll Give A Simple Example.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> my_dictionary=OrderedDict()
>>> my_dictionary['foo']=3
>>> my_dictionar['aol']=1
>>> my_dictionary
OrderedDict([('foo', 3), ('aol', 1)])
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a very short answer to that..
do this--

**dictCopy=yourdictname.copy()**

then use the dictCopy , it will be in the same order.

Comment: Dictionaries in Python have no ordering, thus the question.